# Wrong .offset().top value reported

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a page I have several sections and between first and second I have a navbar menu, when this reaches the top, it triggers a function that fixes it to the top. This works ok by calculating the offset on every scroll, except that sometimes the value is wrong reported and the navbar start to flick.

this is the custom class .css:

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;}
```

and custom .js

```
var checkStickyMenu = function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#secondary-nav").offset().top ){ 
$("#secondary-nav").addClass("sticky")
} 
else { 
if ($("#secondary-nav").hasClass("sticky")){
$("#secondary-nav").removeClass("sticky");
}}}
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
checkStickyMenu();
console.log("scroll " + "win scroll: " + $(window).scrollTop() + " secnav: " + $("#secondary-nav").offset().top);
})
checkStickyMenu();
```

the console.log() gives

```
custom.js:16  scroll win scroll: 1010.8571 secnav: 377.98209999999995
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1011.4286 secnav: 1011.4286
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1018.8571 secnav: 377.98209999999995
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1031.4286 secnav: 1031.4286
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1053.1428 secnav: 377.9820333984376
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1067.4286 secnav: 1067.4286
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1070.8572 secnav: 377.98213896484367
custom.js:16 scroll win scroll: 1071.4286 secnav: 1071.4286
```

as you can see, it jums from 377 (the correct value) to 10XX (that is incorrect), making that the navbar remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

Let check the scroll event raising, especially at last 3 lines in your console log:

When the scrollTop is 1067.4286 and the navbar offset is 1067.4286 and we scroll the scrollTop to 1070.8572, the navbar will be 1070.8572 too (because it is fixed), your checkStickyMenu function will do $("#secondary-nav").removeClass("sticky"). Therefor, your navbar become unfixed and it's offset of course change to another value which will not be equal to scrollTop expectedly (will be 377.98213896484367).

At the next raising event, the scrollTop is 1070.8572 and the navbar offset is 377.98213896484367, your checkStickyMenu will do $("#secondary-nav").addClass("sticky"), and it become the same as when it scrollTop is 1067.4286 (navbar is fixed).

As a result, it just repeats forever. The problem is come from your wrong algorithm.